# amp-list won't show data from firebase rest api while query parameters are added

Tags: rest, firebase, amp-html, amp-list

I am using amp-list with firebase REST api. The thing is when I use 
"https://kitchentocustomer.firebaseio.com/restaurants/Yiecu6fL2Pas0XFhCsT06Q0dSOp1/menu.json"
I get the amp-list populated,but when I add query parameters 
"https://kitchentocustomer.firebaseio.com/restaurants/Yiecu6fL2Pas0XFhCsT06Q0dSOp1/menu.json?orderBy=%22first_cat%22&equalTo=%22BREAKFAST%22&print=pretty"
I get empty amp-list.

Here is the code

```
<amp-list width="300"
                      height="250"
                      single-item
                      items="."
                      layout="responsive"
              src="https://kitchentocustomer.firebaseio.com/restaurants/Yiecu6fL2Pas0XFhCsT06Q0dSOp1/menu.json?orderBy=%22first_cat%22&equalTo=%22BREAKFAST%22&print=pretty">
              <template type="amp-mustache">
                  <div>
                      <dt class="col col-10 h3 mb1">{{title}}</dt>
                      <dd class="col col-2 m0 mb1 self-center right-align">₹{{price}}</dd>
                  </div>

              </template>
            </amp-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [amp-list](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-list/?referrer=ampbyexample.com) response must be a JSON object containing an **array** property.

Your filtered query (second link) returns a JSON object which does not contain an array.

Your response for this should be something like below

```
[
  {
    "discounted": 157,
    "first_cat": "BREAKFAST",
    "id": "eEaVn8",
    "onSale": false,
    "price": 167,
    "third_cat": "Egg",
    "title": "Egg omlete"
  },
  {
    "discounted": 210,
    "first_cat": "BREAKFAST",
    "id": "pia9nL",
    "onSale": false,
    "price": 228,
    "third_cat": "Waffles",
    "title": "Banana & Nutella waffles"
  }
]
```

Comment: How to get that JSON object containing array from firebase REST api query ?

Comment: I am not sure how you do that in firebase. You might have to ask a different question.